# Flutter, google_maps_flutter, rounded Polyline

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Is it possible to round the lines by setting them to drive mode?

like this package "flutter_polyline_points"??

This package is old and not official, so I try to implement it with google_maps_flutter whenever possible.